# iPhone XS Max doesn't adjust native component height

Tags: ios, user-interface, react-native, ios-simulator, iphone-xs-max

When I run my code of iPhone XS it respects native navigation bar and tab bar and adjusts the height automatically. But iPhone XS Max doesn't do the same. Please check attached image.

[image: Simulator comparison].

I am checking on simulator as I don't have real device yet but on left as you can see iPhone XS have proper safe area where as iPhone XS Max doesn't.

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`? If so, which version?

Comment: @MateiRadu Yes, V2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the previous version of [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation), so use the latest version.

OR

Use the [react-native-safe-area-view](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-safe-area-view) wich solves the problem.

Replace `import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'` to `import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-view"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v1, upgrade to lasted 1.6.1 (currently)
or refer to version history on 
[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation?activeTab=versions)